# Adding a custom SSH port to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS through UFW

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, iptables, vps, ufw

I am trying to configure a Ubuntu 12.04 based VPS and I have changed my ssh port from 22 to 803 and everything worked fine. After this I've installed UFW and now I can't login using SSH.

Before I enable UFW I had allowed port 803 (I have checked and its open).

I had also disabled IPV6 support and few other rules because they weren't supported by my VPS and UFW was not starting at boot.

Here are the changes I made to solve the UFW boot issue. But these have nothing to do with SSH.

http://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/2013/04/26/ufw-vps/

http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/

If I disable UFW ssh works and allows the login.

The error I am getting is "Network connection timeout"

I have also tried changing the port back to 22. But it doesn't work.

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same problem as me, this is the solution.

The file /etc/ufw/before.rules, contains a rule “-A ufw-not-local -j DROP”. This rule drops all incoming traffic.

So commenting out this line in the before.rules file will solve the problem.